# IntelliJ IDEA removing the character after on reformatting code

Tags: intellij-idea, kotlin

IntelliJ removes the character after while reformatting. For example if I misspelled "Father" as "Fathr" and want to add an "e" afterwards, the editor removes the "r" on adding "e". I'm new to Kotlin and would really appreciate some help.

Answer (score 1):

I am afraid this is just a simple <kbd>Insert</kbd> key that switches the input mode between insert (a thin cursor) and replace (a fat, character sized cursor).